# When transitioning an SVG line in D3, new line appears instantly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a line chart with time-series data where I want to transition new data coming in for the line:

```
linesGroup.selectAll("path")
    .data([data])
    .join(
        enter => enter.append("path")
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
            .attr("d", line),
        update => update.call(update =>
            update.transition(t).attr("d", line)),
        exit => exit.remove()
    )
```

But when I do so, the new data's line appears instantly and only the old data transitions, as you can see in the example.

I'd like the new data points to transition smoothly from outside instead of them appearing instantaneously. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thank you for your time.

**Edit:** I found [Path Transitions](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/), but I don't grasp how it would apply to extra data.

```js
const width = 500
const height = 300

const margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40}

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr('viewBox', [0, 0, width, height])

const xAxisNode = svg.append("g")
const yAxisNode = svg.append("g")
const linesGroup = svg.append("g")

function update(data) {
    const x = d3.scaleUtc()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
        .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])

    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.value)).nice()
        .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
        
    const line = d3.line()
        .defined(d => !isNaN(d.value))
        .x(d => x(d.date))
        .y(d => y(d.value))
        
    const xAxis = g => g
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0))

    const yAxis = g => g
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

    const t = d3.transition().duration(1000)

    xAxisNode.transition(t).call(xAxis)
    yAxisNode.transition(t).call(yAxis)

    linesGroup.selectAll("path")
        .data([data])
        .join(
            enter => enter.append("path")
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
                .attr("d", line),
            update => update.call(update =>
                update.transition(t).attr("d", line)),
            exit => exit.remove()
        )
}

let data = [
  {
    "date": "2007-04-23T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 93.24
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 95.35
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-04-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 98.84
  },
].map(({date, value}) => ({
    date: new Date(date),
    value: value
}))

update(data)

data = [
  // same points
  {
    "date": "2007-04-23T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 93.24
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 95.35
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-04-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 98.84
  },
  // new points
  {
    "date": "2007-04-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 99.92
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-04-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 99.8
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 99.47
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-05-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 100.39
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-05-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 100.4
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-05-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 100.81
  },
].map(({date, value}) => ({
    date: new Date(date),
    value: value
}))

setTimeout(() => update(data), 1500)
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong example. You don't want to continually add points to your path, you just want to transition from a path to another with different number of data points.

Bostock has [another useful function](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3916621) (here named `pathTween`) which uses an interpolator and a mix of `getTotalLength()` and `getPointAtLength()` to create another `"d"` attribute with the adequate number of points (based on a passed precision argument). In your case, with a precision of 5 pixels:

```
update.transition(t).attrTween("d", (d, i, n) => pathTween(line(d), 5, n[i])())),
```

Here is the snippet:

```js
const width = 500
const height = 300

const margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 30,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 40
}

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr('viewBox', [0, 0, width, height])

const xAxisNode = svg.append("g")
const yAxisNode = svg.append("g")
const linesGroup = svg.append("g")

function update(data) {
  const x = d3.scaleUtc()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])

  const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.value)).nice()
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

  const line = d3.line()
    .defined(d => !isNaN(d.value))
    .x(d => x(d.date))
    .y(d => y(d.value))

  const xAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0))

  const yAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

  const t = d3.transition().duration(1000)

  xAxisNode.transition(t).call(xAxis)
  yAxisNode.transition(t).call(yAxis)

  linesGroup.selectAll("path")
    .data([data])
    .join(
      enter => enter.append("path")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("d", line),
      update => update.call(update =>
        update.transition(t).attrTween("d", (d, i, n) => pathTween(line(d), 5, n[i])())),
      exit => exit.remove()
    )
}

let data = [{
    "date": "2007-04-23T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 93.24
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 95.35
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-04-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 98.84
  },
].map(({
  date,
  value
}) => ({
  date: new Date(date),
  value: value
}))

update(data)

data = [
  // same points
  {
    "date": "2007-04-23T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 93.24
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 95.35
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-04-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 98.84
  },
  // new points
  {
    "date": "2007-04-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 99.92
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-04-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 99.8
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 99.47
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-05-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 100.39
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-05-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 100.4
  },
  {
    "date": "2007-05-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "value": 100.81
  },
].map(({
  date,
  value
}) => ({
  date: new Date(date),
  value: value
}))

setTimeout(() => update(data), 1500);

function pathTween(d1, precision, path0) {
  return function() {
    var path1 = path0.cloneNode(),
      n0 = path0.getTotalLength(),
      n1 = (path1.setAttribute("d", d1), path1).getTotalLength();

    // Uniform sampling of distance based on specified precision.
    var distances = [0],
      i = 0,
      dt = precision / Math.max(n0, n1);
    while ((i += dt) < 1) distances.push(i);
    distances.push(1);

    // Compute point-interpolators at each distance.
    var points = distances.map(function(t) {
      var p0 = path0.getPointAtLength(t * n0),
        p1 = path1.getPointAtLength(t * n1);
      return d3.interpolate([p0.x, p0.y], [p1.x, p1.y]);
    });

    return function(t) {
      return t < 1 ? "M" + points.map(function(p) {
        return p(t);
      }).join("L") : d1;
    };
  };
}
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```